# Flutter: Detect tapping on one widget and releasing on a different one

Tags: flutter, listener, gesturedetector

I want to long press a **first widget** and trigger a function. During the same `PointerDownEvent` (that is, without removing finger or mouse from the screen) continue and drag the finger or mouse to **a second widget**. This second widget should trigger another function when the so named `onPointerUp` event happens.

I was thinking on using `GestureDetector` instances, but they don't seem to have what I am looking for, maybe I'm wrong. Another option would be using `Listener` instances and handling on whether their offsets match the pointer's offset. Could this be the solution? I wonder if there is a more straightforward way.

Something like pressing a key in a phone's keyboard and dragging the finger to select a symbol could be a good example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Draggable` with an invisible child on top of the original widget and each of the targets (in case more than one) can be a `DragTarget`. You then execute your desired function in the `onAccept` property of the `DragTarget`.